# Can TeXForm be forced not to wrap variables in \text{}?

Tags: latex

I have a number of long equations in *Mathematica* that I need to transfer to $\LaTeX$. Unfortunately, the equations involve many variables and `TeXForm` wraps the variables in `\text{}`. My plan was to go through using find and replace to change the *Mathematica* variable names to readable formats, like `f1` to `f_1`. But it seems excessive to have all these `\text{}` and I will have to additionally wrap things in `$$` in order to have math mode inside the `\text{}`.

Has anybody dealt with this before? Is there a way to make `TeXForm` not wrap things in `\text{}`?

Comment: Maybe someone with more experience with `TeXForm` will know what you mean, but could you include an example? I tried `TeXForm[y==Exp[-\[Alpha] l Subscript[x, 3]]` and got y=e^{\alpha  (-l) x_3} ($y=e^{\alpha  (-l) x_3}$) so it seems like it works just fine, but obviously I'm not properly replicating whatever issue you're having.

Comment: Yes, this certainly does happen.  For example `f1 = x + 7` results in `\text{f1}=x+7`.

Comment: @JimB Ah, I see now. It's a problem when there's a variable and a non-subscripted number. I guess the question does provide that example, I just didn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do somthing like this code:

```
(f1 == x + 7) /. {f1 -> Subscript[f, 1]} // TeXForm
```

which returns

```
f_1=x+7
```

and use similar substitution rules for all your subscripted variables.
A simple example of how this can be done is this code:

```
rulex = Table[ToExpression["x" <> ToString@n] -> Subscript[x, n], {n, 3}];
(L == a x1 + b x2 + c x3) /. rulex // TeXForm
```

which returns

```
L=a x_1+b x_2+c x_3
```